# solve this numerical with mass point geometry

Tags: geometry

$AD : DC = 1 : 2, BE : ED = 1 : 2$ and $EF = FC$. Find the ratio of the area of triangle $EFG$ to that of $ABC$.

[image: geometry]

Comment: Using $A = \frac{1}{2}bh$, you know that $\frac{A_1}{A_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2}$.  In this manner you can compare triangles:

$$ \Delta ABC \mapsto \Delta BCD \mapsto \Delta CDE $$

**:-(** You can't compute the area of $\Delta EFG$ this way

Answer (score 2):

Look up **Routh's theorem**. That should solve the problem (along with some mass point geometry, mentioned above).

Comment: Routh's theorem is pretty great!

Answer (score 1):

Start with what John Mangual commented. Continuing with the general method: $[DEF] = 1/2 [CDE]$ and you need to find $EG : DE$ to get the ratio of $[EFG]$ to $[DEF]$.

Using mass points, now:

In $\triangle ACE$, you have $AD : DC = 1 : 2$ and $EF : FC = 1 : 1$. $G$ is the intersection of two cevians, so go ahead and assign masses to the vertices: A (2), C (1), D (1+2 = 3), E (1). This then implies that $EG : GD = 3 : 1$ and $EG : DE = 3 : 4$.